# How to ignore Entity with Doctrine Entity Manager?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures, purge

I'm working on a project using the latest version of the Symfony framework.

I've got some entities that I have created once (I need to keep them for another functionality) but I don't want that the Doctrine Entity Manager purge them when I load new data fixtures with the DoctrineFixturesBundle. (I can't just use the --append option, I need to delete old data from the others tables.)

I have tried to exclude them in the config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        schema_filter: ~^(?!(new_bot_b|new_com|new_str|new_geb|new_geba|new_hea|new_plz1|new_plz2|new_stra))~
```

But it didn't worked.

For the UpdateSchema, CreateSchema, etc. I have overwritten the commands and remove the tables manually before executing but with the fixtures I don't know how to do it.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks!

Geoffrey

Comment: Just use command with `--fixtures` - "The directory or file to load data fixtures from. (multiple values allowed)"

Comment: But will it purge only the tables of the entities for which there are fixtures in this directory?

Comment: I not tested, but you can test it ;), put your other entities fixtures in sepatrate folder.

Comment: It purges the entire database. It doesn't resolve the problem...